# Changing the font in iPython notebook markdown cells

Tags: python, css, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I just wanted to change the default font in Ipython (1.0.0) notebook markdown cells to something else, and tried doing this using style tags in a markdown cell instead of going through the path of creating a custom.css. I do not know CSS, and my needs are very minimal. After some research, I found the following code snippet:

```
<style>
div.text_cell_render {
font-family: "Times New Roman", serif;
...
}
</style>
```

I applied the above CSS code to a markdown cell, however the font in the other markdown text cells did not change. Do I have to turn something on first? Below is how it looks like:

[image: Scrrenshot]

Answer (score 3):

On Ubuntu this works:

```
<style>
.text_cell_render {
font-family: Times New Roman, serif;
}
</style>
```

The `...` in your example indicate other possible options like listed e.g. in http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_text.asp

However, this CSS applies to all rendered cell text, ie. markdown and heading. If you want to format just the markdown text use `.text_cell_render p {`. The individual headings can be addressed with `h1`, `h2`, etc instead of `p`.

Comment: it works in windows, too. But not in OSX for some reason. In neither Safari or Chrome I could make it work.

Comment: Do you have a font named Times New Roman in OSX? Can you try with another font?

Comment: Try "Times". Worked fine for me on OSX.

Answer (score 0):

To change the CSS style in a Jupyter notebook, simply create a cell at the top with the styles:

```
%%html
<style>
.rendered_html p {
    font-size: 17px;
    font-family: Ubuntu Mono;
    text-align:justify}
</style>
```

More information in [here](https://jiafulow.github.io/blog/2019/11/25/jupyter-notebook-css-style/#:%7E:text=To%20apply%20the%20CSS%20style,and%20add%20the%20styles%20there.)